Tailwind custom theme values not accessible in TypeScript helper file
I have a custom Tailwind theme:
// tailwind.config.cjs

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,ts,tsx}'],
  darkMode: ['class', '[data-mode="light"]'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      background: {
        default: 'rgb(var(--background-default) / <alpha-value>)',
      },
    },
  },
};

In my helper I try to access those custom theme color values:
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig';
import tailwindConfig from 'tailwind.config.cjs';

const config = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);

export function themeColor(myTheme: string) {
  let color;

  switch (myTheme) {
    case "default":
      color = fullConfig.theme.colors.background.default;
      break;
    case "black":
      color = fullConfig.theme.colors.background.black;
      break;
    default:
  }
  return color;
}

When I try to access config.theme.colors I get only the default Tailwind colors?
What I am doing wrong?
